# Is it possible to obtain an e-mail address like myname.surname@ubuntu.com

Tags: email, users, community, ubuntu-membership

Being an Ubuntu user for about 3 years, is it possible to obtain an e-mail address like myname.surname@ubuntu.com ?

Comment: I guess only the Ubuntu members can get a username@ubuntu.com Email IDs.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you became an Ubuntu member you get the benefit of an @ubuntu.com email.

Here is how you can become an Ubuntu member: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Membership

Ubuntu members are people who are helping the development and growth of Ubuntu. It does not require coding or packaging. You can be an Ubuntu member by just contributing to translations or marketing.

By just using Ubuntu it is not that easy to get an email address.

Comment: In your opinion, what should I do in order to confirm my Ubuntu Membership ?