# Can anyone get an myname@ubuntu.com email address?

Tags: email, ubuntu-email-address

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to obtain an e-mail address like myname.surname@ubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13007/is-it-possible-to-obtain-an-e-mail-address-like-myname-surnameubuntu-com)

If it is possible how can I get one?

Comment: Am guessing only developers or anyone related to the development, design and production of Ubuntu

Answer (score 5):

An @ubuntu.com email address is a benefit of [Ubuntu Membership](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Membership):

> ## Benefits of Membership
>
> Membership entitles you to the following
>   benefits:
>
> - Voting privileges to confirm Ubuntu Community Council nominations.
> - **An @ubuntu.com email alias that forwards to your real email address.
>     See UbuntuEmail for more details.**
> - An ubuntu/member/your_nick cloak on freenode - See IRC/Cloaks.
> - The right to print business cards with the Ubuntu logo - The business
>     cards can be found at the
>     BusinessCards page, you will need to
>     take care of the printing yourself.
> - Syndication on Planet Ubuntu of your Ubuntu blog or the Ubuntu category
>     posts in your blog, if you have one.
>     Follow the registration instructions
>     on PlanetUbuntu to add your blog!
> - An Ubuntu Member title at the Ubuntu Forums. See this post for more
>     information.
> - A subscription to Linux Weekly News - see this page for instructions on how to apply.
> - Ability to join the Official Ubuntu Members group on LinkedIn. See
>     Membership/LinkedIn for more
>     information.
> - Signing up for SixXS account with an Ubuntu email address and a link to
>     your Launchpad page will grant you an
>     "Ubuntu Credit Bonus" of 25 credit
>     points.
> - SFTP access to a Web-accessible directory on people.ubuntu.com

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

Comment: It would be nice if anyone could get an @ubuntu.com account. I don't like gmail or hotmail, or... for many reasons. I do like Ubuntu, so I would like to have also an Ubuntu mail. If it is open to anyone it might become popular.

Comment: @Gonzalo : @ubuntu.com email id is just an alias. You have to use gmail or hotmail or any mail service to host your mailbox.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you too can get myname@ubuntu.com email. For this you should become an active participant in Ubuntu development. Get started with [http://launchpad.net](https://launchpad.net/) . Report bugs you encounter in launchpad, try to help by making patches. The best method to get into it is through packaging. For this you need to become a member of MOTU. It takes time to learn the whole thing. Do check https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MOTU/FAQ to get started with MOTU.

Comment: myname@ubuntu.com will be just a forwarding mail id, that means you will not get actual storage space for your mail like gmail or hotmail, it just forwards the mail to your real email address yourname@gmail.com