# Is there a Mastodon or Pleroma or other Fediverse (ActivityPub) instance with committed support from Ubuntu/Canonical?

Tags: tools

As part of the movement towards the [Fediverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fediverse) (federated Internet publishing and social media platforms) and away from the currently dominant platforms that exist to sell user data to advertisers, various organizations are providing their participants with supported instances of federated platforms like Mastodon, Pleroma, Peertube, and WriteFreely.

For example, Ubuntu provides members with email addresses and the [PlanetUbuntu](https://planet.ubuntu.com/) blogging instance as noted at [Can anyone get an myname@ubuntu.com email address? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30859/can-anyone-get-an-mynameubuntu-com-email-address/30863#30863).

See also Debian's approach at https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/DebianSocial.

Does Ubuntu/Canonical plan to provide these sorts of collaborative tools, to facilitate participant collaboration, networking and outreach in a safe, secure and well-integrated environment?

Does PlanetUbuntu support ActivityPub for federated connections?

Comment: This seems like a question you want to ask at discourse.ubuntu.com instead. It seems like a policy question more than a technical support question; voting on answers won't really matter to this question.

Comment: @user535733 Hmmm, that probably makes sense now. I did check this first [What topics can I ask about here? - Help Center - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) and I guess adding a similar tip and link there to our Discourse at [Ubuntu Community Hub](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/) would be helpful.